# How to pass “this” from a QML element to a JS Function

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Similar to the `this` keyword in C++, I’d like to either have a QML element to pass itself into a JS function, or have it set a property on another element to itself. Is this possible?

For example:

```
Rectangle{
id:theParent

property var theElement

SomeElement{
id:theChild
   MouseArea {
        anchors.fill:parent
        onClicked: {
            someJsFunction(*whatGoesHere*)
            parent.theElement=*whatGoesHere*
        }
    }
```

Or, Consider this:

```
Rectangle{
id:theParent

property var theElement

SomeElement{
id:theChild
    }
```

Then, in SomeElement.qml:

```
Rectangle{
   MouseArea {
        anchors.fill:parent
        onClicked: {
            someJsFunction(*whatGoesHere*)
            parent.theElement=*whatGoesHere*
        }
}
}
```

In this case, the `*whatGoesHere*` would be the instance of SomeElement where these are being called from.

Is this possible in QML? I would think the `id` property would make sense, but according to the docs, you cannot query the value of the `id` field, and anyway the `id` wouldn't be available if my `SomeElement` was described in a separate file, and the *whatGoesHere* handling above appeared in that separate file rather than in a particular instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have two complementary proposals :

First, for a single usage, pass the ID as it's basically a pointer to the item :

```
MouseArea {
    id: myClicker;
    onClicked: { callFunc (myClicker); }
}
```

Then if you need multiple items to share this behavior, that means you're using MVC so the ID will work exactly the same :

```
Repeater {
    model: 100;
    delegate: MouseArea {
         id: myClicker;
         onClicked: { callFunc (myClicker); }
    }
}
```

That is the classical part.

But to todo even better if you create your own components, keep in mind to create a 'self' helper property that does the 'this' job properly :

```
MouseArea { // component root definition
    id: base;

    property var self : base; // bind self on the I
}
```

Then use it like this :

```
Repeater {
    model: 100;
    delegate: MyComponent {
         onClicked: { callFunc (self); }
    }
}
```

Use this as often as you want !

Comment: Nice solutions, do you have a recommendation for components defined in c++ and exposed via `qmlRegisterType()` ? Can a `QObject*` typed `Q_PROPERTY` that points to `this` be used?

Answer (score 0):

Instance of your `SomeElement` is its `id` property value i.e. `theChild`. You can use it as `this`. No other built-in way exists as far as I can tell. But you can try to add your own QML item hierarchy with property which will return `this`.

Another way is to get children of some parent and use them. So you get children, locate the child you need and use that particular instance

Comment: Suppose I have many `SomeElement`s and I want this functionality defined in SomeElement.qml not in-line as in my code. The `id` would then not be available inside the SomeElement.qml since it is not an instance (yet).

Comment: Add name to each `SomeElement`, get children of the parent(which contains those `SomeElement`s) and find what you need by name. Then use. It's very simple

Comment: Sure, looping through all children of the parent is one way to do it, but I was hoping for direct access as per the implied behavior of my code above. But I suspect this isn't idiomatic in QML

Answer (score 0):

If you define your element in a separate file, then you can simply assign an `id` and use it. It will be valid just within the context of that instance:

**SomeElement.qml**

```
Rectangle{
   id: thisElement
   MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            someJsFunction(thisElement);
            parent.theElement = thisElement;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple SomeElements in another file, several instances, each will have its own ID. Are you saying that the `onClicked` is smart enough to replace the `thisElement` you have in the SomeElement.qml file with the eventual instance's ID as set in another file?

Comment: It wont replace anything: think of the two ids as two pointers pointing to the same object.